# Moving files to Trash Can in Linux using C++

Tags: c++, linux, recycle, recycle-bin

I'm trying to move (delete) a file to a Trash Can (in Linux) using C++ (also using QT4 for GUI). Unfortunately it seems to be quite difficult to do so and as far as I can tell there isn't a unified API for it.

I would like for my application to run not only on KDE but on GNOME, Xfce and other Linux desktop environments. That's why I'm searching for a more universal approach.

The best I could find so far is:

- [send2trash](http://www.hardcoded.net/articles/send-files-to-trash-on-all-platforms.htm) - but that's using Python/QT4 and not C++/QT4
- [trash-cli](http://code.google.com/p/trash-cli/) - this has the drawback of being a stand alone command line program and not a library

I would be happy with any approach that requires as little desktop environment specific code as possible. Or in other words that's as much independent from KDE/GNOME/Xfce components as possible.

Any help in finding a solution (if there even is one) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you look at how trash-cli does it?

Comment: This link might help you: http://www.ramendik.ru/docs/trashspec.html

Comment: You are both right, but that would be a last resort solution. It's reinventing the wheel. In other words instead of using a lib it would mean writing one.

Also trash-cli just like send2trash is written in Python in which I have no experience.

Comment: The original FreeDesktop spec is [here](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec); AFAIK at least KDE, Gnome and XFCE follow it, and it's the one supported by `trash-cli`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not find a terminal command to move the files and then call [system()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) to run it for you inside your C++ program?

[This](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-script-how-to-move-files-to-trash-instead-of-deleting-819103/) *might* (I haven't tested it) be a possible one-liner in Linux to move files to the trash via the terminal. You would just pass the command as a quoted string to `system()` and call it in your C++ implementation.

Comment: It's similar to the trash-cli I've mentioned in my original post. The problem with your solution is that it doesn't account for Trash Cans and files on other partitions/drives. It just moves them (and if it's on another drive - copies them between drives) to your home Trash Can. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: `std::system("gio trash ...")` worked great for me

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in

http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec

> For every user a “home trash” directory MUST be available. Its name and location are $XDG_DATA_HOME/Trash

you only need to write C++ code move your file into such directory.

You can move files using [boost file system](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem) and you can retrieve the XDG_DATA_HOME value using [cstlib getenv](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/getenv/).

Comment: Is it likely that the "MUST" means "IF you are to conform"? As it is, my Redhat Enterprise Linux box at work does not have a XDG_DATA_HOME environment var set by default. My Trash is in $HOME/Desktop/Trash/.directory ...

Comment: I run Ubuntu 11.04 and there is no such folder in my home directory. But cstlib getenv will be useful for me in other ways, thank you.

Comment: How widely is this implemented?

Comment: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications lists this under *Draft specifications that are new and not yet widely used*.

Comment: Thx, Paŭlo. That explains a lot.

Comment: what's about restoring files from bin later? can they be restored via restore button from bin by user?

Comment: @Engos on Ubuntu the trash is here: /home/YOURUSERFOLDER/.local/share/Trash/files/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no standard trash can in Linux in the first place.

Comment: OP seems to be well aware that this feature lies in each window manager.